# Javascript synthesizer only plays once

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to make a JavaScript synthesizer to be playable from keyboard keys. I have written the code for detecting a pressed key and detecting a released key, so the playback of the tone generator stops, but for some reason I can only play it once. Then, after it stops playback (on release), it won't play again. The only keyboard key that currently works is A. https://jsfiddle.net/linushg111/z062nnn1/7/

```js
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
document.onkeyup = stops;
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'sign';

// create Oscillator node







function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '65') {
    /*C4*//*A*/
oscillator.frequency.value = 650; // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.start(1);

      
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '87') {
    /*C#4*//*W*/
    alert("test")
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '83') {
    /*D4*//*S*/
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '69') {
    /*D#4*//*E*/
    }
}


function stops(){
oscillator.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);
 oscillator.stop();
}
```